# actions on google home app not calling token exchange endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-smart-home

Everything is ok before token exchange. I found that Google Home showed "something went wrong,try again." It seems that the account linking was failed. I checked the official document, but I could not find the point that where is wrong.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyl1I.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NzVp.png)

Our OAuth server's log:
14:30:09.322 [https-jsse-nio-9000-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - [doFilterInternal,218] - Securing GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=home-control-google&redirect_uri=https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/smarthome-63b16&state=AGsGMl0x-_cveABQcrOPo1I0RVk6fFwzA328sn87humHtmb_d33ppy7MtK0bnqRKJnKKocsJlIGBZyqUBfZnmskiIi5lFU4Kfus9gVFJeQAqyWoKOUwKUbKo5xl3ieM-ElcYYqMJJ0M4IJ5L171QldMLmeAoIJPlSoIgB4-cTx5NQoXYdcFgj4deBZ8p1GA1ucuT_UlTc72irf8GXlLg19geMnJ0W6-PE8cRlx0gN22Qj8AzsmXRRj_h0N6unvRIIfJI-7NaFdmVpYVQBuXzZYi-ajjcLLhiQYLSveVFnbSv-HS2P8mRuZvXhooPoqnj9j7yg0TPDaXPsS3myHb7G1Ka9UHIXHy6yQnEtboQQhLPfHzw204raLk4FzxzUqF4RGz7I8RZu8ExGopO0NkXk4xHn51oLJumyAs6FRJ6n38sYw43yWboa1q3KjAqiPs-2AxqHofL1Hzq-xmWKvKNx5D1i80toVi3nIQys_EPOje89qWH6cWgcuiJ2s4-l_ZIkuw0GK1YT61_dg9XSW2ACJ72agnY2k81vTZYJt1yuh_kGgg83_oqbjcsazr2x9gF_beVxOxq65H9xxYE0D8m2tiNJRaS5CUvygQLJjqCoOy1JozI0sgS9dy6warYk7mc9KPg27e5LagQmEYdghtG_5t5iluzNX4jag
14:30:09.353 [https-jsse-nio-9000-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - [readSecurityContextFromSession,189] - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=linesware, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=58.56.179.134, SessionId=E1CD90937DE27B197B6DA53D47FA0454], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]
14:30:09.384 [https-jsse-nio-9000-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - [doFilter,109] - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=linesware, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=58.56.179.134, SessionId=E1CD90937DE27B197B6DA53D47FA0454], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]
14:30:11.556 [https-jsse-nio-9000-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy - [sendRedirect,57] - Redirecting to https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/smarthome-63b16?code=O1h-RSPrRnKn45aWutuafiC3EkB_jVVJU-AJfRwdB177-xq1BIJ2fHbftdaMNHZ1Zv70YkKvtHkHZGKO5kAwoqYGmK0ATXAAnSYmyNg_cdQ5Q9V2YnVhs3RUkUr1lYtb&state=AGsGMl0x-_cveABQcrOPo1I0RVk6fFwzA328sn87humHtmb_d33ppy7MtK0bnqRKJnKKocsJlIGBZyqUBfZnmskiIi5lFU4Kfus9gVFJeQAqyWoKOUwKUbKo5xl3ieM-ElcYYqMJJ0M4IJ5L171QldMLmeAoIJPlSoIgB4-cTx5NQoXYdcFgj4deBZ8p1GA1ucuT_UlTc72irf8GXlLg19geMnJ0W6-PE8cRlx0gN22Qj8AzsmXRRj_h0N6unvRIIfJI-7NaFdmVpYVQBuXzZYi-ajjcLLhiQYLSveVFnbSv-HS2P8mRuZvXhooPoqnj9j7yg0TPDaXPsS3myHb7G1Ka9UHIXHy6yQnEtboQQhLPfHzw204raLk4FzxzUqF4RGz7I8RZu8ExGopO0NkXk4xHn51oLJumyAs6FRJ6n38sYw43yWboa1q3KjAqiPs-2AxqHofL1Hzq-xmWKvKNx5D1i80toVi3nIQys_EPOje89qWH6cWgcuiJ2s4-l_ZIkuw0GK1YT61_dg9XSW2ACJ72agnY2k81vTZYJt1yuh_kGgg83_oqbjcsazr2x9gF_beVxOxq65H9xxYE0D8m2tiNJRaS5CUvygQLJjqCoOy1JozI0sgS9dy6warYk7mc9KPg27e5LagQmEYdghtG_5t5iluzNX4jag
14:30:11.556 [https-jsse-nio-9000-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - [doFilter,120] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request

Exchange authorization codes for access tokens

Answer (score 0):

Account Linking through Google Home App consists of two steps: Users are sent to your Authorization Url to provide credentials and complete the consent flow. Once this process is completed successfully, your server gets a token exchange request containing the authorization code at your Token Url. In order to debug this flow, you might need to understand if your credentials exchange completes successfully. You can learn more from the [Account Linking Documentation](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/primer/account-linking) for Google Home.

If you still have issues after this step, make sure to take a look at the [Troubleshooting](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/analytics/troubleshooting) flow. You can also go through the introductory [codelab](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer) to try these out in a brand new project with a functioning OAuth 2.0 implementation to compare against your project/implementation.